# Can a thread be logically interruptible while waiting for a mutex?

Tags: multithreading, unix, thread-safety, pthreads, mutex

I was reading R&R's Unix system programming, I encounter a question about mutex. For the following paragraph stated in that book. When he said a thread that waits for a mutex is not logically interruptible, does it mean when a thread wait for a mutex, it won't be able to do a context switch? Can someone elaborate it?

> A thread that waits for a mutex is not logically interruptible except
>   by termination of the process, termination of a thread with
>   pthread_exit (from a signal handler), or asynchronous cancellation
>   (which is normally not used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't mean that it can't context switch.  On the contrary, a thread waiting for a mutex that is already acquired almost always *will* context switch away, perhaps after a short delay.

All it means is that the `pthread_mutex_lock()` call won't return `EINTR` or similar - it will either successfully acquire the mutex, or return persistent failure.